# Celery is refusing to deserialize content of my custom serialization throwing ContentDisallowed Exception

Tags: python, serialization, openssl, celery

I have been using celery with rabbitmq as my backend queue to manage my tasks.
There are objects containing datetime attributes which cannot be serialized using json and so I chose to use pickle as serializer.

Problem being security related it reports untrusted content cannot be deserialzed.
After going through this link http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html#guide-security
I have generated private key and associated self-signed certificate usinf ***openssl*** and configured auth settings accordingly.
This time I see the error as ExpiredCerticate for which I didn't find any related docs.

So I wrote custom seriailizer as following after which It throws same kind of error as pickle saying

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return {
                '__type__': '__datetime__',
                'epoch': int(mktime(obj.timetuple()))
            }
        else:
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def datetime_decoder(obj):
    if '__type__' in obj:
        if obj['__type__'] == '__datetime__':
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(obj['epoch'])
    return obj

# Encoder function                                                                                                                                                                                               
def datetime_dumps(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, cls=DateTimeEncoder)

# Decoder function                                                                                                                                                                                               
def datetime_loads(obj):
    return json.loads(obj, object_hook=datetime_decoder)
```

***ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type serializer (application/x-serializer)***

Can someone please guide how do I proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not exactly a solution for the above , but you can the following work around.
By default in kombu serialization file (serialization.py) invokes a function that disables all the available serializers (pickle included)

```
from kombu.serialization import registry
registry.enable('pickle')
```

It will enable pickle serializer disregarding whether content is trusted or untrusted.
ofcourse thi is a hack . Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks Bharath. Even though it's a work around this really helped me.